# Simplifying splitting seconds into years, days, etc

Tags: java, datetime

I have to code a program which calculates seconds into years, days, hours, minutes, seconds.

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long s = IOTools.readLong("Give seconds:");
    long a = s / 31536000;
    long t = (s % 3153600) / 86400;  
    long h = ((s % 3153600) % 86400) / 3600;
    long m = (((s % 3153600) % 86400) % 3600) / 60;
    long r = (((s % 3153600) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

    System.out.println( a + " year(s) " + t + " day(s) " + h + " hour(s) " + m + " minute(s) " + r + " second(s)!");            
}
```

I want to make it simpler, for example with an if-else condition. Something like: divide the seconds by 31536000, save it in `a`. When there is a remainder, do this, and so on. But I have no idea how to start.

Also I have problems to typecast. I don't want to use `long` all the time, as it is not necessary anymore when the program calculates the days.

Comment: You only need to do the last modulo operation on each line, since the previous constants are multiples of the last constant.

Comment: Just use a `Duration` from Java 8's Time API or Joda Time.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest you can use the remainder after each step:

```
long s = IOTools.readLong("Give seconds:");
long a = s / 31536000;
s %= 31536000;
long t = s / 86400;
s %= 86400;
long h = s / 3600;
s %= 3600;
long m = s / 60;
long r = s % 60;
```

Comment: you are sure about that answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `Calendar` class here can be pretty handy and you'll avoid complicated calculations. After you read the seconds from the input, you'll just have to convert them into milliseconds and pass the result to a `Calendar` instance.

Then, you can fetch the day, month, year like this:

```
long s = IOTools.readLong("Give seconds:");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(s * 1000);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal("your input");
    long longVal = input.longValue();
    int hours = (int) longVal / 3600;
    int remainder = (int) longVal - hours * 3600;
    int mins = remainder / 60;
    remainder = remainder - mins * 60;
    int secs = remainder;

    System.out.println("hours: "+hours);
    System.out.println("Mins: "+mins);
    System.out.println("Sec: "+secs)
```

Comment: It seems odd to use a `BigDecimal` if you are going to immediately convert it to a `long`.